# Convert a dictionary to a list of SelectListItem VB.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I normally programming in C# but have be asked to use vb.net for my current website and was wondering how you would convert the below C# code into vb.net code.

The code converts a dictionary to a list of SelectListItem's

```
return dic.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.Value.ToString(), Value = x.Key.ToString(), Selected= EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x.Key, selectedKey) });
```

Any help would be amazing.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query syntax* is often more readable in VB.NET:

```
Dim result = From kv In dic
     Select New SelectListItem() With {
         .Text = kv.Value,
         .Value = kv.Key,
         .Selected = EqualityComparer(Of SelectListItem).Equals(kv.Key, selectedKey)
     }
```

<sub>* It's also more pewerful than in C#</sub>

Answer (score 1):

```
return dic.Select(Function(x) New SelectListItem() With { .Text = x.Value.ToString(), .Value = x.Key.ToString(), .Selected = System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer(Of T).Default.Equals(x.Key, selectedKey) })
```